# Get a javascript derived dom-tree element

Tags: javascript, php, html

My aim is to get an element `<div id="calender">` and all what is in the element shown in a browser. The point is that normal get-html-source won't do the thing. The element what I am looking for does not exists in the html output of php-function file_get_contents.

I have tried to get the source by php with xpath byt the help of https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php which inludes a nice tool to get what is in any tag in the html page. But the problem here might be that the element (a calender) is formed to the loaded page by javascript and cannot be caught by server side php. So, is there a way I can catch such element (div) by javascript instead.

There are script examples of javascript for this kind of problem (if I have understood them correctly) but currently I cannot get a simple javascript to work. An example below shows how I have tried to built up a code. $ajax thing here is just one path I have tried to solve the problem but don't know how to use it. More here I cannot figure out why the simple javascript functions do not work (just test purposes).

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="fi">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>load demo</title>
    <style>
    body {
    font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    </style>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ok {
        alert "OK";
        }
    function get_html (my_html){
        alert "OK";
        var l = document.getElementById('my_link').value;
        alert l;
        alert my_html;
        var url = my_html;
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html'
        success: function(data){
                //do something with data, which is the page 1.html
            var f = fs.open("testi_kalenteri.html", "w");
            f.write(data);
            f.close();
            alert "data saved";
            }

        });
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <p id ='my_link' onclick='get_html("lomarengas.fi/en/cottages/kuusamo-rukasaukko-9192")'>html-link</p>
    <p id ='ok' onclick='ok()'>show ok</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Briefly, I have a link to a web page, which shows up a (booking) calendar in it but this calendar is missing in the "normal" source code, by file_get_contents (php). If I browse the html source with Chromes tools (F12) I can find the calendar there. T want that information get by javascript or by php or such.

Comment: Could you share the site from where you are trying to take the calendar?

Comment: Sure, this is the link example to a page I am talking about www.lomarengas.fi/mokit/kuusamo-rukasaukko-9192

Comment: The same with less cryptic language: http://www.lomarengas.fi/en/cottages/kuusamo-rukasaukko-9192

Answer (score 2):

If you **read the source code** of the page you point to (http://www.yllaksenonkalot.fi/booking/varaukset_akas.php), you notice that the calendar is loaded via an **[iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)**.

And that iframe points to that location :

http://www.nettimokki.com/bookingCalendar.php?id_cottage=3629&utm_source=widget&utm_medium=widget&utm_campaign=widget

Which is in fact the real source of the calendar...

---

**EDIT following your comment on this answer**

Considering the real link : http://www.lomarengas.fi/en/cottages/kuusamo-rukasaukko-9192

If the calendar is not part of the generated html, it is surely asynchronously generated (in javascript, client side).

From this asumption, I inspected the source code (again).
In the developper tools of my browser, in the Network section, where you can monitor what files are loaded, I looked for 
calls to server (everything but calls to resources : images, stylesheets...).

I then noticed calls to several urls with json file extensions like http://www.lomarengas.fi/api-ib/search/availability_data.json?serviceNumber=9192&currentMonthFirstDate=&duration=7.

I felt I was on the right track (asynchronous javscript calls to generate html with json datas), I looked for javascript code or files that was not the usual libraries files (jquery, bootstrap and such).

I stumbled upon that file : http://www.lomarengas.fi/resources_responsive/js/destination.js.
It contains the code that generates asynchronously the calendar.

**tl;dr**

The calendar is indeed generated asynchronously.

You can't get the full html with a `curl` or `file_get_content` in PHP and
you can't access it with ajax code (due to [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)).

By the way, you should contact the site to see if you can access their api via PHP **with their consent**.

Hope it helped you understand the whole thing...

Comment: Sorry, that I have confused you with all my information but the refernece with iframe was not a problem. It was there just to test my javascript. The problematic site link  is www.lomarengas.fi/en/cottages/kuusamo-rukasaukko-9192

Comment: No problem, but you should update your question to point to the correct page. My answer will then be irrelevant, ...

Comment: Impressive search work, thank you! Although the result was not exactly what I hoped... But there is apparently nothing more to do but contacting the site.

Comment: I think I still got an idea of getting what I want with json file extension. But let's see how it further behaves.

Answer (score 1):

To get `<div id="calender">` you can use next code (jquery):

```
<div id="calender"></div>
<script>
$("#calendar").click(function(){
alert('calendar was clicked');
});
</script>
```

If I understand you correctly. I think you need appropriate php respond with some correct code inside php file:

```
// json_handler.php
<?php


if (is_ajax()) {

    $return = $_POST;

    $return["ok"]="ok";

    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);

}


function is_ajax()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
```

and this is script wich is inside html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a id="click">click</a>
    <script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        var data = {
            "request": "request"
        };
        data=$.param(data);
       // alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "json_handler.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
            // here you will see echo respond from your php json_handler.php
            // also you can add here more javascript (jquery code) to change your page after respond
            alert();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
    </script>
    <body>
    <html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: As I can see, the main point here in using ajax is to have reference to ajax source code. Some other fixes too. Thanks, I will try this! This is the first time I am even trying to use ajax. But still this is solving an ajax code technical issue, I still don't know exactly how I am solving my main problem (about the html source).

Comment: Yes. and best practice is to use `alert('some alert text');` 
but not `alert "some alert text";`

Comment: I'm still not sure this will work, because the .calendar div is filled with a script on load.  AJAX will only get you the html file and this is what that div looks like:

    `<div class="calendar">
        <div id="bookingcalendar-single" class="lr-datepicker single"></div>`

Comment: If you want to select you div by using id  `$("#calendar").click(function(event){ alert(); })`    and if you want to select div by using class name then use another jquery selector `$(".calendar")`